# Having some trouble getting started mining bitcoins using GUIMiner and Radeon HD 5770 graphics card

Tags: miner-configuration

I wanted to give mining bitcoins a go. I set up a wallet and downloaded [GUIMiner](http://guiminer.org/). I also signed up for [Slush's pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Pooled_Mining) and all of that fun stuff.

However, my GPU seems to not accept anything. I have zero accepted and two stale/invalid.

My CPU is running GUI and has accepted shares. It's running at ~3.6 Mhash/s.

My GPU is [HIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hightech_Information_System)' [Radeon HD 5770](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_5000_Series#Evergreen_.28HD_5xxx.29_Series). It also says it's running at ~890 Khash/s which seems low. It's stably overclocked and has been for some time now. How do I properly set up this GPU on GUIMiner?

My current preferences are set to `-v -w128` - that I saw that on the hardware settings Wikipedia page.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it "why is my 5770 only getting 890KH/s"? And do you mean HIS? And are you sure you didn't download the scrypt version of GUIminer?

Comment: Ya my question was "Can anyone run through how to properly set up this GPU on GUI miner?". And ya I meant to put HIS I apologize. However, the answer below made me rethink bitcoin mining. I am currently mining LTC instead and am seeing some pretty decent results with the 5770 so i'll just stick to that. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any point in mining with a CPU or GPU. You can get just a few MHash/s that are not enough to accept work from pools. If you want to mine, you have to have at least 1 GHash/s, and you need to buy specific hardware, like ASIC miners. There are a few companies like Butterfly Labs, KnCMiner and more where you can buy machines. The most recent one is from KnCMiner that release preorders for Neptune, a 3000 GHash/s machine for about 12,000 dollars.

You can also look at some cloud mining like [cex.io](https://cex.io/r/1/giagola/0/). The price per GHash is much more, but you can trade GH any time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is going to waste money. Bitcoin mining with video cards is unprofitable because of the cost of power. What I would recommend doing is how I am setting up. I am sure there might be a better way, but it's the easiest way I learned how to start to make a profit.

Yea, I just setup my mining setup through [cex.io](https://cex.io/r/0/Sunbasher/0/). All I did was setup a [coinbase.com](http://cur.lv/5hf1h) account and bought 0.3 bitcoins for $200, and now I have a buy order in for 5 GHash/s at .06 Bitcoin per GHash/s. No hassle, and I don't have to worry about the electricity bill. Still, I have to pay a maintenance fee, but I do have the benefit of all the extra merge mining I get from it.